# Регулярное выражение, ошибочный паттерн

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Мне нужно проверить строку на соответствие определённому шаблону. Шаблон имеет вид:

```
#include "любой-текст"
```

Для этого я написал следующий код:

```
string line = "#include \"../lights/lights.ps\"";
cmatch result;
regex reg("(\\s*)(#include)(\\s+)(\")([\\w-]+)(\")(\\s*)"); 
if (!regex_match(line.c_str(), result, reg))
{
    // no
}
```

Однако regex_match возвращает ложь. В чем моя ошибка? Я проверял регулярное выражение [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/VKEDlO/1), и оно функционирует. Подозреваю, что дело в неправильно построенном мною синтаксисе регулярки для cpp...
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: так у вас  !(regex_match) возвращает ложь, или  regex_match?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan проверяю я regex_match, если он возвращает ложь. Все правильно же вроде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы же сами пишите образец строки `string line = "#include \"../lights/lights.ps\"` там есть символы, которые не входят в класс `\w-`. Вам, как минимум надо его расширить

```
[\\\/\.\w-]
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/VKEDlO/2)

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам! Совсем забыл, что \\w - это далеко не все символы..